# How to create single RegistryKey and refer to it from many RegistryValue's?

Tags: wix

I created a RegistryKey and a RegistryValue nested inside this RegistryKey. Later I created another RegistryValue - not nested inside whatever RegistryKey in WiX's XML scheme. But I want to this second RegistryValue be inside the first RegistryKey actually after the installation complete. So I want to refer from many RegistryValue's to a single RegistryKey. How to do it?

It also requires that various registry values will be inside various components, so I can't put all the registry values inside a single registry key within the WiX scheme.

The example is presented below.

```xml
  <Component>
    <RegistryValue
      Root="HKLM"
      Name="ShortcutInstalled"
      Key="SetupAndAccessoryData1"
      Type="integer"
      Value="1"
      KeyPath="yes"
      />
  </Component>
  <Component>
    <RegistryKey
      Id="SetupAndAccessoryData1"
      Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall"
      Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)\SetupAndAccessoryData"
      Root="HKLM"
      >
      <RegistryValue
        Type="string"
        Name="InstallDirectory"
        Value="[ProductDirectory]"
        KeyPath="yes"
        >
      </RegistryValue>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

For now I must fill the Key attribute of the ShortcutInstalled RegistryValue with the same data as in the Key attribute at the RegistryKey. But I don't want to copy and paste it because of refactoring difficulties. I just want to refer to the same registry key. What is the best approach to gain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RegistryKey` element is mostly provided for convenience when you have many `RegistryValue` elements to nest under a single key. However, it is not necessary to use `RegistryKey` element since `RegistryValue` can provide the full path as well. Your example above could also be written like:

```
<Component>
  <RegistryValue
     Root="HKLM"
     Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)\SetupAndAccessoryData"
     Name="ShortcutInstalled"
     Value="1"
     Type="integer" />
</Component>
<Component>
  <RegistryValue
     Id="SetupAndAccessoryData1"
     Root="HKLM"
     Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)\SetupAndAccessoryData"
     Name="InstallDirectory"
     Value="[ProductDirectory]"
     Type="string" />
  </RegistryValue>
</Component>
```

It's mostly a matter of preference. Alternatively, if you need to refer to the same registry key in many `Components` then you could use a preprocessor variable to store the common part of the path, then use it across many `RegistryValue` elements. For example, we could modify the above to look like:

```
<?define CommonReg = "SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)\SetupAndAccessoryData" ?>
<Component>
  <RegistryValue
     Root="HKLM"
     Key="$(var.CommonReg)"
     Name="ShortcutInstalled"
     Value="1"
     Type="integer" />
</Component>
<Component>
  <RegistryValue
     Id="SetupAndAccessoryData1"
     Root="HKLM"
     Key="$(var.CommonReg)"
     Name="InstallDirectory"
     Value="[ProductDirectory]"
     Type="string" />
  </RegistryValue>
</Component>
```

Comment: Rob, but I want to use the same key for these values. And I won't to copy and paste this key to many RegistryValue's key attribute (because of it's hard to follow the changes at all these attributes at various registry values). How to do it?

Comment: Whether WiX has a reference-like mechanism or something like this to escape the problems under refactoring?

Comment: Added to my answer the option of using a preprocessor variable to address these comments.

Comment: Thanks, Rob! I just don't know that preprocessor variables can contain another preprocessor variables.